# Automated testing with SAP

Tags: automated-tests, abap, sap-gui, sap-enterprise-portal

I'm looking for help on a couple of things.

1.) Does anyone have any advice/recommendations on automated testing solutions for SAP?

2.) Does hp's Unified Functional Test (UFT) have a framework that integrates with SAP?

I appreciate the help, and thanks in advance.

Comment: SAP has its own [eCATT: extended Computer Aided Test Tool](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/1b/e81c3b84e65e7be10000000a11402f/content.htm) (Sorry, no detailed answer from my side. I used eCatt, but I have not big experience with it).

Comment: I'm keen to hear if anyone has used Selenium with Fiori?

Comment: Keep the most common [test automation mistakes](https://learntestautomation.com/test-automation-mistakes/) in mind when creating your automated tests.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of different options here:
SAP has a number of legacy methods available broadly described under SeCATT  and these cover the SAP GUI testing.
Additionally there is the Solution Manager (SOLMAN) integrated testing workbench which can be used together with HP's QTP/Quality Center as part of SAP TAO

The advantage of using the SOLMAN approach is that in theory you can identify an issue or bug in the SOLMAN service desk, promote this to a development fix, have it fixed in SOLMAN, promoted to QA, tested in QA and deployed in PROD with the full lifecycle documented and assured. That's the theory at least.

QTP has the benefit of being suitable for more than just SAP GUI testing too including portal and browser based applications.

Many SAP customers would choose a hybrid approach using a combination of tools and I only know of a few that have committed to just using QTP for everything.

You can also look at the offerings of Borland but I don't know of anyone using these for SAP

Answer (score 0):

1) ABAP supports unit tests with [ABAP Unit](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/ABAP+Unit). So you can cover your code with unit tests using techniques like [Test Driven Development](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Driven_Development).

[SAP eCATT](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/1b/e81c3b84e65e7be10000000a11402f/content.htm) provides you a way to test your system via SAP GUI, but I would not recommend it, because it is [not worth](http://googletesting.blogspot.com.br/2007/10/automating-tests-vs-test-automation.html).

2) I am not sure. Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Back when I used to perform SAP testing, our client had bought a tool called Worksoft-certify. They work well with SAP GUI & SAP Portal(areas I worked on with the tool primarily). They have built-in steps for SAP, they come in handy for quick scripting. The shortcoming (vs QTP) I came across about this tool is, it has no coding at all you cannot customize your test step with code and have heard the client cribbing about the cost of the license sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Automated testing is ideal for flawless business execution with SAP. The company I work for, Worksoft, has automation software for SAP testing that delivers end-to-end quality assurance. Since companies use and customize SAP in many different ways, it’s important that you find an automated solution designed to test SAP business processes the way you use them and to meet your specific objectives. Our software can help ensure business process quality end-to-end, across all applications, technologies, interfaces, devices, and geographies. From functional and regression testing, to high-velocity daily testing, it handles every SAP process.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate submitting of incidents using an add-on: https://sta-technologies.com/ticket-system-for-sap/

This allows you to submit error reports from the SAP GUI and all details will be attached to the ticket automatically.

Simple but useful.